# Blank Country Column - Magento Order Grid

Tags: magento-1.9, order-grid

I added a Country column to the order grid but it appears blank! Can anyone see why this might be?

My Grid.php (rewrite) is below!

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Adminhtml
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * Adminhtml sales orders grid
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Adminhtml
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Splitpixel_OrderGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('sales_order_grid');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve collection class
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getCollectionClass()
    {
        return 'sales/order_grid_collection';
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_address', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id',array('telephone','city','postcode','country_id' ) )->where("sales_flat_order_address.address_type =  'billing'");
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

        $this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order #'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'index' => 'increment_id',
        ));

        if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
                'index'     => 'store_id',
                'type'      => 'store',
                'store_view'=> true,
                'display_deleted' => true,
            ));
        }

        $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
            'index' => 'created_at',
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'width' => '100px',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
            'index' => 'billing_name',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('shipping_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ship to Name'),
            'index' => 'shipping_name',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('base_grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Base)'),
            'index' => 'base_grand_total',
            'type'  => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Purchased)'),
            'index' => 'grand_total',
            'type'  => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('status', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
            'index' => 'status',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'width' => '70px',
            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
        ));

        $this->addColumn('country_id', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Country Id'),
            'index' => 'country_id',
            'filter_index' => 'sales_flat_order_address.country_id',
        ));

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
            $this->addColumn('action',
                array(
                    'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Action'),
                    'width'     => '50px',
                    'type'      => 'action',
                    'getter'     => 'getId',
                    'actions'   => array(
                        array(
                            'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('View'),
                            'url'     => array('base'=>'*/sales_order/view'),
                            'field'   => 'order_id',
                            'data-column' => 'action',
                        )
                    ),
                    'filter'    => false,
                    'sortable'  => false,
                    'index'     => 'stores',
                    'is_system' => true,
            ));
        }
        $this->addRssList('rss/order/new', Mage::helper('sales')->__('New Order RSS'));

        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel XML'));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getAllCountry(){

    $options = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')->load()->toOptionArray();
    $countries = array();
    foreach($options as $options){
         $countries[$options['value']]=$options['label'];
        }
    return $countries;
    }

    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        parent::_prepareMassaction();

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('auit_pdfdocs_order_all', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Orders'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('auit_pdf/order/printall'),
        ));
        if (Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XPATH_CONFIG_SETTINGS_IS_ACTIVE)) {

            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('orders2csv', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Orders2CSV'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_orders2csv/makecsv'),
            ));
        }

        return $this;
    }

    const XPATH_CONFIG_SETTINGS_IS_ACTIVE       = '../community/orders2csv/settings/is_active';


    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
            return $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $row->getId()));
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the class I was extending it should have been:

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
```

Comment: COULD U PLS EXPLAIN BRIEFLY

Comment: "class Splitpixel_OrderGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid" should have been "class Splitpixel_OrderGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid" from what I remember.

Comment: could you pls share me your code.